# Is there a way to "bundle" rules from a CSS framework so I can DRY up my HTML, without needing to use SASS or JS templates?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, less

I keep running into this problem with CSS frameworks like Material. Naturally, they require you to use a bunch of classes. But this means your HTML starts getting super un-DRY with enormous and repetitive `class=""` attributes.

For example, you get things like:

```
<div class="css-framework-class-1 css-framework-class-2 css-framework-class-3"></div>
```

The usual ways to address this seem to be:

## 1. Use SASS or LESS

`import` the CSS framework, then make your own CSS rules that include/extend/mixin classes from the framework. For example,

```
.mybutton{
  @extend .css-framework-class-1, .css-framework-class-2, .css-framework-class-3;
}

<div class="mybutton"></div>
```

...but when my CSS compiles, it duplicates the CSS of all those classes I `@extend`ed. This seriously beefs up the size of my compiled CSS.

## 2. Use componentized CSS

...or otherwise use custom components and directives. Pseudocode:

```
new Template('mybutton', ()=>{
  return <div class="css-framework-class-1 css-framework-class-2 css-framework-class-3"></div>
})

<mybutton></mybutton>
```

But unless I'm already planning on using a JS framework, I don't want to include Webpack or Gulp and a bunch of JSX to address CSS problems.

## Here's my idea:

I write my HTML with a custom attribute like this:

```
<div custom-attribute="mybutton"></div>
```

Then, in a JSON/YAML/something file, I map what I put in my custom attribute to CSS rules from the framework:

```
{
  "mybutton": "css-framework-class-1 css-framework-class-2 css-framework-class-3"
}
```

Then I write some front-end JS that looks for that custom attribute, maps its value using the JSON file, and converts my HTML above into this:

```
<div class="css-framework-class-1 css-framework-class-2 css-framework-class-3"></div>
```

That way I could use the framework and sort-of bundle together its classes without my users needing to load a bunch of redundant CSS.

Is this a crazy idea? Is there already some JS package that does this?

Comment: I think the hit(and choppiness as the styles are applied) from parsing the page with js to the end user will be a worse experience than dealing with the larger css file. I guess it depends on the file growth though. What kind of size change do you mean when you say `beefed up` ?